# Is it possible to modify const parameters of a function using ebpf uprobes?

Tags: linux, kernel, trace, ebpf, uprobe

I am trying to modify the behaviour of a function from a shared library during runtime using eBPF uprobes. Is there any way to change a const char* parameter of the function when the function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to change a const char* parameter of the function when the function is called?

The `const` qualifier is for the compiler; it doesn't impact how you can instrument the code at runtime.

You can write such parameters with the `bpf_probe_write_user` [BPF helper](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html). See [`samples/bpf/test_probe_write_user.bpf.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.6/samples/bpf/test_probe_write_user.bpf.c) for a usage example of that helper (with kprobes but the principle should be the same for uprobes).

Comment: Great to hear! Don't hesitate to officially accept the answer to help with indexing & co.